# Relatively positioned text clipped, even with visible overflow

Tags: css

I'm creating a scheduling web-app and am using coloured blocks to indicate availability, for which I'm using an empty div with a background colour. Now I'm trying give these blocks labels above them, using a nested div with relative positioning. The problem is that the text in the label div is clipped, even though the overflow property of the blocks are set to visible.

My css for this is:

```
.om-wrap{
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: visible;
   margin: 0 auto;
   white-space: nowrap
}
.time-end{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.time-start{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.slot{
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow: visible;

}
.slot:first-of-type{
clear:both;
}
.slot-avail{
    background-color: green;
}
.slot-break{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.slot-full{
    background-color: red;
}
.slot-wrap{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.om-label{
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    left:-10px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

And the HTML is formatted like this:

```
<div class="om-wrap">
    <div>
        <div class="time-end">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="time-start">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slot-wrap">
        <div class="slot slot-full" ><div class="om-label">19:00</div></div>
                <div class="slot slot-full" ><div class="om-label">19:00</div></div>
                <div class="slot slot-full" ><div class="om-label">19:00</div></div>
                <div class="slot slot-full" ><div class="om-label">19:00</div></div>
                ...
        </div>
</div>
```

I've created a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GknLH/

I've searched the internet for a solution to this, but as I can't even find a single forum post, on what appears to be a simple issue, I've probably been wording it wrong, so I apologise if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove `overflow: auto;` for `.om-wrap`.

Check this updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GknLH/1/)

Comment: The only issue is that there is now a vertical scroll in browser and in the jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks, but I've managed to get rid of it by setting a minimum height